# save image from django form to model

Tags: django

I am beginner in django and i am facing a problem that is how to save image from django form to database but image=check.cleaned_data.get('pro_image') return None(ImageField).

```
#forms.py
         class Up(forms.Form):
             STATUS=(
                  ('Sale','Sale'),
                  ('Rent','Rent'),
                  )
             status=forms.ChoiceField(choices=STATUS)
             pro_image=forms.ImageField(required=False)
                
#views.py
                    
def create(request):
     form=Up()
     context={'form':form}
     check=Up(request.POST or None)
     if request.method == 'POST':
        if check.is_valid():
           image=check.cleaned_data.get('pro_image')
           status=check.cleaned_data.get('status')
           print(image)
           print(status)
           try:
              up=Uploaded()
              if image==None:
                 up.image='/media/default/item_default.png'
              else:
                 up.image=image
                 up.status=status
                 up.save()
                 except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                 return render(request,"create.html",context)
         return render(request,"create.html",context)
     return render(request,'create.html',context) 
                     
#modles.py
                    
 class Uploaded(models.Model):
     image=models.ImageField(upload_to='media/test')
     status=models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Comment: show us your html template with form

Comment: please edit your question with formatted html so it will be readable

Comment: why image field return None instead of image name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change `check=Up(request.POST or None)` to `check=Up(request.POST, request.FILES or None)` and then in your form tag in html it should be `<form method='post' enctype='Multipart/form-data'>`